# jQuery highlight and hover function

Tags: jquery

I have 6 images in a row, the first one I want scaling and a shadow on, then if any of the other images are hovered over they scale up and apply a shadow (through a class) and the most important thing is I want the orinal image to scale back down and remove shadow if another image is hovered over.

I have this so far, although its probably written completley wrong you will say!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gallerySlideshow li img:first").css('-moz-transform', 'scale(1.1)').addClass('test');
    $("#gallerySlideshow li img").hover(function(){
        $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'scale(1.1)').addClass('test');
    },
function () {
        $("#gallerySlideshow li img:first").css('-moz-transform',  'scale(0.9)').removeClass('test');
},
    function () {
        $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'scale(0.9)').removeClass('test');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your hover function have three argument.Forget to paste correct code?

Comment: @sathishkumar is right. Hover can only take two functions. Check out the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: It looks like you are applying classes AND css. You should try to include all css in ready made classes then add multiple classes if you  really need to.

Comment: So what is the question here?

Comment: Hover will accept two argument as function,But in your codes it has three function as argument to the hover?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulating styles using `css` method I would suggest to use class. Also as mentioned by others your have 3 callback functions to `hover` method which only needs at the most 2 functions. Try this code which has fixed your issues and also using the classes to scale and show the shadow.

Css

```
img{
   //default style, add whatever style you want here
   -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
}
.scaleAndShadow{
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);//Apply on hover
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gallerySlideshow li img").hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('scaleAndShadow')
        .siblings().removeClass('scaleAndShadow');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('scaleAndShadow');
    })
    .first().addClass('scaleAndShadow');//Set the class to first img on load
});
```

Note: The style which you are using `-moz-transform` will only work in `Firefox`, you have to use other equivalent styles to support other browsers.

Comment: Hi Shankar, Thanks for your help, I'm starting to understand what your doing with the code sent, thanks. It does not quite do what I need yet though and I cant see how to manipulate it. Essentialy I have 6 images, when the page opens the first one has the class applied to it, then if the user hovers over any of the other 5 they have the class applied and the first one has the class removed, then if the user does not hover over any images in the list the first one has the class applied to it again.